# Trigonometry functions

Tags: trigonometry

How do I verify the following identity:

$$\frac{1-(\sin x - \cos x)^2}{\sin x} = 2\cos x$$

I have done simpler problems but got stuck with this one.
Please help.

Tony

Comment: are you sure your brackets are in the right place?

Comment: Multiple across by $\sin x$ and use a basic relationship involving $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$.

Comment: What you've written isn't an identity, it's an equation. An equation asks "For which values of $x$ are the left- and right-hand sides equal." For an identity, you need to use $\equiv$. For example $\cos^2x+\sin^2 \equiv 1$. This means that the left- and right-hand sides are identical. So writing $\cos^2x + \sin^2x \equiv 1$ is the same as saying that $\sin^x+\cos^2=1$ for all values of $x$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: An identity (according to every trig book I've ever seen) is is an equation that holds *whenever both sides of the equation are defined.* This is an identity in that sense.

Comment: @CameronBuie I agree 100%. If $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ for all $x$ then $\sin^2x + \cos^2x \equiv 1$. (Which is of course true.) However, an equation, in general, is *not* an identity.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1-(\sin x -\cos x)^2}{\sin x}=\frac{1-(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)+2\sin x\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{2\cos x\sin x}{\sin x}=2\cos x$$

Here I used the identity: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$